# How do each agent specify different parameters?

Tags: anylogic

I am modeling the type of Customer agents. They are given parameters: they work (true / false) and have education (true / false).

There is a condition that agents in the block service fall where works == true and education == true. And all the others go to the exit.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sA1f.png)

How do each agent specify different parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing to notice here is that your queue block does nothing and you could just remove it.

And to change the parameters of your agent, in your source, in the "on at exit" action you can write the values you want, for instance:

```
agent.works=false;
agent.education==true;
```

you can also create random values...

```
agent.works=randomTrue(0.5);
agent.education==randomTrue(0.5);
```

also, if you go to your agent's variable "works", in the default value, you can make it also random writing `randomTrue(0.5)`

where randomTrue defines how likely it is for your variable to be true (0.5 means 50% chance)

Comment: I modified the model. Created a population of agents customers with parameters: work(true/false) and education(true/false). I set the condition that there will be only 9 agents. An example on screenshots:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SQCMKYE9ldtldAIaJeqzgEaY8a9Vl1XE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0SLlM4_SLnJANOTinbxT1em0xJ984ya/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6JQXod_KQr6Yz2QImBqMPmCfGB9aCaF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: But at work, the agents are not properly generated. According to the condition, there were two agents, and only one is in the population list. Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1six5JayjFTpa-pEAz9ahN7LmNVgsyXxS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: because the agents that you are looking at are the 9 initial agents that you created in your initial population. 

The other 9 agents that went through your flowchart disappeared already on the sink, so you can't know what their parameters are.

In fact, your model works fine, but you are just confused about the results. Make your initial population equal to 0 to avoid confusion

Comment: I understand. And I can somehow display a list of agents with parameters, so that we can see what parameters in agets?

Comment: you can put a wait block before the sink so your agents don't disappear... That's it

Comment: And the last question. How to make the text field "fieldText" show the number of agents who went through the block service (those who have true and true)?

Comment: fieldText.setText(  selectOutput.countT() )